# React, Material-UI, Grid empty item

Tags: material-ui

I have this code:

```
<Grid item xs={12}>
    <Grid container spacing={8} >
        <Grid item xs={3} ></Grid>

        { someState && <SomeComponent /> }

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

At the first render, `someState` will be always `false` and only when I change that state I will show `SomeComponente` but I need to have that Grid visible and empty, in other words, using the row space in the dom. I don't want it hidden. How can I do it? I tried by putting the `Grid`component empty as I show in the code, but the Grid container isn't using that space.

```
const SomeComponent = () => (
    <Fragment>
        <Grid item xs={3}>
            <Typography variant="body1">Title</Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={3}>
            asdasdasd
        </Grid>
    </Fragment>
);
```

Comment: How much space do you want SomeComponent  to occupie?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<Grid item xs={3} >{someState && <SomeComponent />}</Grid>
```

This will create the Grid regardless of `someState` and will fill the space, after `someState` is thruthy.